# Problem with adjusting the box line width

Tags: dia, linewidth

For some reason, even if I set the line width of the boxes to the minimum (0.00cm), it still stays very bold when exported to pdf. I've been searching for a solution but to no avail.

[screenshot of flowchart in dia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlPBX.png)

[screenshot of flowchart in pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOph8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found a workaround that fixed the problem. Exporting it as a svg file then converting that to a pdf file does the job

Just do this:
[image: Export as svg]